# Change asset upload path based on locale

Tags: assets, localization

We have a localized site with separate public directories. I'm looking for a method to handle image uploads for the different asset paths.

For example when uploading an asset within a particular locale, the image will be deposited in that `public_*/uploads` folder.

[image: Asset Upload Locale]

I thought perhaps concatenating the `{craft.locale}` in the asset path might work but it threw an error. I'm thinking that the locale doesn't change when selecting the language from the sidebar or asset dropdown.

[image: AssetPaths]

I'm pretty stuck on this one and there doesn't seem to be any answers online. Any other ideas or solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`{craft.locale}` won't work because the single curly brace syntax is short for `{{object.craft.locale}}` where `object` is the element that is currently being edited (in your case, the entry).  You can read more about that here: https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths

Your screenshot shows the double curly syntax, though (which should work fine).

Alternatively you could use `{locale}`, which would translate into `{{object.locale}}`, which would be the currently locale of the entry.